# Error - Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "path" is not supported

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting below error after upgrading cordova `8.0.0` to `9.0.0` in my ionic 3 application

```
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "path" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
```

I wanted to install cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics plugin which requires cordova version `9.0.0`

I tried `npm cache clear --force` command and building it again but it didn't work.

I also updated all the plugins to the latest version, removed the platform and added it again, still getting the same error.

I read all the related posts and tried them but the solutions given there are not working in my case.

Kindly help me with this error.

Comment: Where you see Cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics require Cordova 9 and don't work on 8 ?

Comment: @Sam While installing the plugin i got this message -
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.0.0,
failed version requirement: >=9.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics' for android